# Using AWK to take a range of columns and print them as a single column

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file where I want to print every entry for a column i>N followed by the contents of the next column.  Each line has the same number of columns.  An example input:

```
a b c d 
a1 b1 c1 d1 
a2 b2 c2 d2 
a3 b3 c3 d3
```

say in this case I want to skip the first column so the desired output would be

```
 b
 b1
 b2
 b3
 c
 c1
 c2
 c3
 d
 d1
 d2
 d3
```

I got close to what I wanted using

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; print $i; i++)}'
```

but this prints each entry in a line consecutively instead off all entries from each column consecutively.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get a syntax error with that awk script. Though that's close to the awk script you would want to print each field spread out over N lines. In order to do what you want you are going to need to accumulate values from each column individually until you are done with the file and then print them all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every line has same number of fields then you can do:

```
awk '
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
        rec[i]=(rec[i]?rec[i]RS$i:$i)
}
END {
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print rec[i]
}' file
```

If the number of fields are uneven, then you need to remember which line has the maximum number of fields.

```
awk '
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        rec[i]=(rec[i]?rec[i]RS$i:$i)
    }
    num=(num>NF?num:NF)
}
END {
    for(i=2;i<=num;i++) print rec[i]
}' file
```

**Output:**

```
b
b1
b2
b3
c
c1
c2
c3
d
d1
d2
d3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` would be easier here:

```
# figure out how many fields
read -a fields < <(sed 1q file)
nf=${#fields[@]}

# start dumping the columns.
n=3
for ((i = n; i <= nf; i++)); do
    cut -d " " -f $i file
done
```